# Blocking Happening in IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted Isolcation level?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My same query some times takes milliseconds and some times takes more than 90 seconds. From my application, I am setting `IsolationLevel = ReadUncommitted`. Here is my SP that is causing causing the issue,

```
UPDATE  MyTable
    SET [Action] = ISNULL(TP.[Action], T.[Action]) -- If TP.[Action] is null take the old value
        ,[ErrorDescription] = ISNULL(TP.[ErrorDescription], T.[ErrorDescription])
        ,[ID] = ISNULL(TP.[ID], T.ID)
FROM    MyTable T
        CROSS APPLY MyUdf(....)  AS TP
WHERE   .......;
```

This SP is calling a UDF and here is the line in UDF causing issue,

```
IF(EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM MyTable  WHERE ..............))
BEGIN
    --.......................
END
```

Now from SQL Server All Blocking Transactions Reports, I am seeing these 2 statements. Also these 2 lines are expensive(according to a query)

Note both the UDF and SP is using the same table(MyTable). I am not understanding why this SELECT is blocking because the connection's `IsolationLevel = ReadUncommitted`?

Comment: Can you move your UDF out into your SQL. This might improve performance and reduce lock escalation. What is your query actually trying to do?

Comment: @ElectricLlama, my UDF query is simply setting some variable that are then use in Update statement. See above I ahve, `ISNULL(TP.[Action], T.[Action])`. This will take UDF value or old value. How to move this UDF?

Comment: How do you put it in your SQL? That depends on what you're passing into it and what it does. Usually SQL Server can optimise your SQL better if it is all 'inline' rather than calling a UDF. i.e. it can join on indexes etc. rather than having to pass values into a black box udf.

Answer (score 1):

> I am seeing these 2 statements. Also these 2 lines are expensive(according to a query)

You should post your actual observations, not your interpretation. Post the actual query you run and the actual results you get.

You should use snapshot isolation to avoid blocking, not dirty reads. [Dirty reads are inconsistent reads](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx) and you will get incorrect results back.

As to why are dirty reads blocking, there could be several reasons. For one, you did not post the actual code how you submit the queries, you did not prove that the SELECT *are* dirty. Most likely you are doing read committed reads and ordinary data blocking. But even if you do really dirty reads, dirty reads can block on schema stability blocks. And any sort of activity would block behind a data/log growth event.

Comment: I just omitted the WHERE condition. and in the `IF(EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM MyTable WHERE ..............)) BEGIN --....................... END`I am just setting a variable. Nothing special. I am suspicious that UDF is not running under read-uncommited snapshot.